# Can't get Java do while loop to break

Tags: java, loops, do-while

A simple yet disgruntling problem with my wallet program, everything seems to be working properly when adding money to my wallet but I can't seem to break out of my do-while loop when inputing "-1" as my moneyChoice.

```
private static void AddItemToWallet()throws IOException{
boolean valid=true;
String input;
int moneyChoice;
char addToWallet;

do{
  out.println("\n\n======================================================");
  do{
    out.println("Please enter choice to add (integer) --->");
    //display money choices
    System.out.println("Avaliable moneys to add:\n");
    for (Money money : Money.values()) {
      System.out.print(money.ordinal()+1 + " --- ");
      System.out.print(money + ": ");
      System.out.println(money.GetDenom());
    }
    //scanner=new Scanner(in);
    moneyChoice=scanner.nextInt();
    if (moneyChoice > 11 || moneyChoice <= -2 || moneyChoice == 0) {
      out.println("Your choice is not valid.");
    } 
  }while(moneyChoice > 11 || moneyChoice <= -2 || moneyChoice ==0);

  out.println(moneyChoice);
  do{
    try{
      valid=false;
      scanner=new Scanner(in);
      //confirm choice
      out.println("Add item to wallet? (y/n)");
      input=scanner.nextLine();
      addToWallet=input.charAt(0);
      if (Character.toLowerCase(addToWallet)=='n'){
        out.println("Selection " + moneyChoice + " was not added to wallet.");
        valid=true;
      }else if (Character.toLowerCase(addToWallet)=='y'){
        out.println("Selection " + moneyChoice + " was added to wallet.");
        valid=true;

        Money money = Money.PENNY; 
        if(moneyChoice ==1){ 
          money = Money.PENNY;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==2){ 
          money = Money.NICKLE;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==3){ 
          money = Money.DIME;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==4){ 
          money = Money.QUARTER;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==5){ 
          money = Money.HALFDOLLAR;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==6){ 
          money = Money.ONE;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==7){ 
          money = Money.FIVE;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==8){ 
          money = Money.TEN;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==9){ 
          money = Money.TWENTY;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==10){ 
          money = Money.FIFTY;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }
        if(moneyChoice ==11){ 
          money = Money.HUNDRED;
          wallet.add(money.GetDenom());
        }

        System.out.println(money);



        //Using a Switch and set ENUM
        Money foundMoney = money;
        switch (foundMoney) {
          case PENNY:
            money = Money.PENNY; 
            System.out.println("Pennies are useless");
            break;
          case NICKLE:
            System.out.println("Why did the fan go to the concert? To get their Nickle back!!! Man are they horrible.");
            break;
          case DIME:
            System.out.println("How come Dimes are the smallest coin? So strange.");
            break;
          case QUARTER:
            System.out.println("Tom Brady, best Quarterback eva!!!!");
            break;
          case HALFDOLLAR:
            System.out.println("Half Dollar coin. Have you seen one???");
            break;
          case ONE:
            System.out.println("One is the lonliest number.");
            break;
          case FIVE:
            System.out.println("Five Buck Lunch, here I come!!!");
            break;
          case TEN:
            System.out.println("Ten is what grandma gave you for graduation.");
            break;
          case TWENTY:
            System.out.println("Twenty Bucks. 2 0... awesome.");
            break;
          case FIFTY:
            System.out.println("Fitty Sploondocks.");
            break;
          case HUNDRED:
            System.out.println("I did it for the Benjamins. Get rich or die trying.");
            break;
        }
      }
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
    if (!valid){
      out.println("That is not a valid answer");
    }
  }while(!valid);  
 }while(moneyChoice!= -1);
```

}

Comment: And while debugging line by line you learned that...?

Comment: add a space after the `moneyChoice`

Comment: You should break this up into smaller methods. It's needlessly difficult to follow.

Comment: You should also indent the code correctly. Most people will find 4 spaces to be preferable for java syntax.

Comment: ... and remove duplicate code. You only need one `wallet.add(money.GetDenom());` -- after the series of `if` statements, not inside each of the "then" blocks of the `if` statements

Comment: Does `moneyChoice=scanner.nextInt();` pick up a `-1` for the string `"-1"`, or does it just pick up a `1` ?

Comment: @ChickenFeet: The [Google Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) prescribes 2 spaces for indentation.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it is a good idea to get in the habit of *never* writing an empty `catch` block.  At the very least, put `ex.printStackTrace();` in there.  If something goes wrong, you want to know why and where, right?

Comment: I just ran your code (with irrelevant sections hollowed out) and it works. See http://ideone.com/X2BtDE
 My guess is the nextInt() function isn't reading negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Your program can basically be reduced to the following

```
do {
    // read moneyChoice

    do {

         // Perform logic

    } while ( ! valid );

} while ( moneyChoice != -1 );
```

Note that after you read `moneyChoice`, you *always* go into the `do` that performs the logic. There is nothing there that checks whether the `moneyChoice` you entered was `-1`. So the logic is performed anyway, and only then, when you hit `while ( moneyChoice != -1 )`, it will stop.

You should add an `if` such that the logic will only be performed if the `moneyChoice` that was read is not -1.

```
do {
    // read moneyChoice

    if ( moneyChoice != -1 ) {
        do {

         // Perform logic

        } while ( ! valid );
    }

} while ( moneyChoice != -1 );
```